# How can I set the default value of a file input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to set default value for a file input. Basically I am working on a form, where user should be able to edit already created inputs. User should be also able to change already uploaded image.

With text inputs it is easy, you put `defaultValue` and you are good to go. But with type of file inputs seems to be different, while just putting the url as a default value is not working.

Here is [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/datepickerex-forked-mh2rzs?file=/src/App.js) and code example

```
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [imagePreview, setImagePreview] = React.useState();

  console.log(imagePreview);

  const onImageChange = (event) => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length > 0) {
      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      reader.onload = () => {
        setImagePreview(reader.result);
      };
    }
  };
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        id="inputImage"
        name="inputImage"
        type="file"
        onChange={onImageChange}
        alt="image"
        className="upload-box"
        required
      />
      <div className="bg-black">
        {imagePreview && (
          <img
            src={imagePreview}
            alt="preview"
            className="h-64 w-full object-contain"
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: It doesn't make sense to have a default value for `<input type="file" />`, because the browser cannot access files on the system with a given file path anyway. What you can do is simply to have a default image set for `imagePreview` state instead (e.g. a base64 string of whatever default image you want). That is your "default file".

Comment: @Terry thanks for the answer. Understand. 
But what should be the initial value of imagePreview?
Url?

Comment: The reason , I am asking, that the consoling the imagePreview is weird long string

Comment: It should be a base64 string or a URL, doesn't matter: anything that you'd put in the `src` attribute of an `<img>` element

Comment: Here is an example of url, that supposed to be the default value, or as you said, default image, but doesn't work.
"/uploads/fabio_henning_Ciqwz8_GF_5_WM_unsplash_46ba212a20.jpeg
"

Comment: Well, where is that image being hosted? You should treat it like _any other image_. Check your network tab to see if the browser resolves the image path correctly.

Comment: Status is 404 putting the url from api as img src attribute

Comment: "Request URL: http://localhost:3000/edit/ds/fabio_henning_Ciqwz8_GF_5_WM_unsplash_46ba212a20.jpeg"

Comment: Then you need to figure out why that's the case: that's not the point of the question already.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [Emeka Orji](https://dev.to/code_rabbi/programmatically-setting-file-inputs-in-javascript-2p7i) for the original idea. This is just an example, and thus does not run alone (please DO NOT RUN). I hope you will use your imagination and resourcefulness to fill in the blanks.

The `useEffect` part is where you really have to pay attention to, since that's what the error tell you to do.

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export type Image = { url: string; fileName: string };

export type ImageFieldProps = {
  image: Image | undefined;
  setImage: (image: Image) => void;
};

export const ImageField = ({
  image,
  setImage,
}: ImageFieldProps): JSX.Element => {
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = new DataTransfer();
    data.items.add(new File([''], image?.fileName ?? 'No file chosen'));
    if (inputRef.current !== null) {
      inputRef.current.files = data.files;
    }
  }, [image?.fileName]);

  return (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      title={image?.fileName}
      type='file'
      className='w-full file:w-0 file:p-0 file:-m-1 file:invisible hover:cursor-pointer file:hover:cursor-pointer'
      onChange={(event) => {
        const file = event.target.files?.[0];

        if (file !== undefined) {
          const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
          setImage({
            fileName: file.name,
            url: fileURL,
          });
        }
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```